# Is it possible to use tlmgr to install required LaTeX packages in macOS 13.2

Tags: installing, mactex, macos

I do not want to install the full TeX Live in macOS 13.2 with an M1 chip, I just want to use this command:

`tlmgr install scheme-small`

to install only required packages with minimal disk usage. Is it possible to use `tlmgr` to install a small LaTeX collection? If so, how? I did not find anyone talking about this. I only found this command to install a full distribution: `brew install texlive`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the [BasicTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) distribution which is very small and then use `tlmgr` to install any other packages you need. Since Homebrew simply runs these installers there’s no advantage to using it to install TeX Live on a Mac.